# Update GCC compiler in Ubuntu 14.04 to 4.9

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, gcc

Can I upgrade my GCC compiler now in Ubuntu 14.04? Has the final usable version (4.9) been released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some core packages never get their versions upgraded in a release. GCC is one of those. Neither GCC [4.7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gcc-4.7&searchon=names) nor [4.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gcc-4.8) were ever available for Ubuntu 12.04 officially (even via `backports`). GCC 4.9 is only being built for [14.10 and 15.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.9). You'll have to use the Toolchain PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
```